# Pulse Audio and Roaming Profiles on CentOS 6

Tags: centos, nfs, pulseaudio

We've been testing many Red Hat based distributions recently at work to replace Windows as our main operating system. We choosed CentOS 6 since all our software were fully compatible. The biggest bug I got so far comes from Pulse Audio.

When I log as a local user (root and non-root), I've no problem at all. But when it comes to a network user (roaming profiles) through NFS, it seems that Pulse Audio can't start. I've been looking at the system logs, and it was complaining about the fact that it couldn't create a socket, so we changed the config file to create it locally. The daemon stopped complaining and started, but still can't get the audio working. Going to System/../Audio pops the window to configure, but I get this message: Waiting for Audio [...] and never show up like on a local user session.

I don't have any logs at the moment, I'll post them tomorrow. I was just wondering if this is a known issue and if it's possible to fix it? I've been searching for a while but never found an answer.

The solution I found so far was to uninstall pulse audio (and all related ALSA plugins) and use Alsa directly. It works, but I think having pulse audio would be more convenient for our users (So they can configure their usb or other audio component more easily than with ALSA, and some software works better with Pulse Audio).

Thanks

Edit:

Here are some logs:

After a Fresh install of pulse audio

[...]

```
Sep  2 09:42:06 localhost pulseaudio[20545]: main.c: Module load failed.
Sep  2 09:42:06 localhost pulseaudio[20545]: main.c: Failed to initialize daemon.
Sep  2 09:42:06 localhost pulseaudio[20539]: main.c: Daemon startup failed.
Sep  2 09:42:06 localhost rtkit-daemon[20011]: Warning: Reached burst limit for user '1090', denying request.
Sep  2 09:42:06 localhost rtkit-daemon[20011]: Warning: Reached burst limit for user '1090', denying request.
Sep  2 09:42:07 localhost rtkit-daemon[20011]: Warning: Reached burst limit for user '1090', denying request.
Sep  2 09:42:07 localhost rtkit-daemon[20011]: Warning: Reached burst limit for user '1090', denying request.
Sep  2 09:42:07 localhost rtkit-daemon[20011]: Warning: Reached burst limit for user '1090', denying request.
Sep  2 09:42:07 localhost rtkit-daemon[20011]: Warning: Reached burst limit for user '1090', denying request.
Sep  2 09:42:07 localhost rtkit-daemon[20011]: Warning: Reached burst limit for user '1090', denying request.
Sep  2 09:42:07 localhost pulseaudio[20551]: module-protocol-stub.c: Failed to remove stale UNIX socket '/Network/Servers/[some path]/Volumes/Home/Users/xavier/.pulse/0a9e231ce3558be2c6df990d00000013-runtime/native': No such file or directory
Sep  2 09:42:07 localhost pulseaudio[20551]: module.c: Failed to load  module "module-native-protocol-unix" (argument: ""): initialization failed.
Sep  2 09:42:07 localhost pulseaudio[20551]: main.c: Module load failed.
Sep  2 09:42:07 localhost pulseaudio[20551]: main.c: Failed to initialize daemon.
Sep  2 09:42:07 localhost pulseaudio[20542]: main.c: Daemon startup failed.
```

[... Keeps looping.]

Then I modify system.ps and default.pa in /etc/pulse with this:

```
load-module module-native-protocol-unix socket=/tmp/pulse.socket
```

Now the logs are different:

```
Sep  2 09:46:13 localhost pulseaudio[22179]: pid.c: Daemon already running.
Sep  2 09:47:10 localhost rtkit-daemon[20011]: Sucessfully made thread 22187 of process 22187 (/usr/bin/pulseaudio) owned by '1090' high priority at nice level -11.
Sep  2 09:47:10 localhost pulseaudio[22187]: pid.c: Daemon already running.
```

Still have no sound.

Then I try:

```
[xavier@theatre ~]$ pulseaudio -k
[xavier@theatre ~]$ pulseaudio --start -D
```

Which results in:

```
Sep  2 09:49:11 localhost rtkit-daemon[20011]: Sucessfully made thread 22238 of process 22233 (/usr/bin/pulseaudio) owned by '1090' RT at priority 5.
```

... but I'm out of luck.

Answer (score 1):

I recently encountered this issue in one of our computer labs running CentOS 6. I was able to make Pulse show up and work for the roaming profile user by adding them to the **pulse** and **pulse-access** groups. This didn't even require a relog, audio just magically started working when I did this.

This seems to only apply to the local user-- that is, the changes will persist when that user logs on to the same workstation, but won't travel with the user to other workstations. I'm afraid I don't know enough about roaming profiles to fix that issue.

Comment: I'm having very strange behavior after doing this. Something else is going on, and I guess it's not as simple as I thought. For example, Flash movies in Chrome can play sound, but mplayer run as my user cannot. mplayer run as root can play sound, and seems to spawn a second pulseaudio instance that crashes the driver. Something is clearly amiss. I'll keep investigating anyway.

Comment: Hmm, yeah I gave it a try but still had the issue. I guess I'll keep going with Alsa for now. I'd be curious to see if there are any improvement with the new 1.0 release.